# I have an error useing a c style statement in swift?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myScrollView: UIScrollView!
    override
    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.myScrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        let myImages=["cat1.png","cat2.png","cat3.png","cat1.png","cat2.png","cat3.png","cat1.png","cat2.png","cat3.png"]
        let imageWidth:CGFloat = 275
        let imageHeight:CGFloat = 147
        var yPosition:CGFloat = 0
        var scrollViewContentSize:CGFloat=0;
        for var index=0; index<myImages.count; index++
        {
            let myImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: myImages[index])!
            let myImageView:UIImageView = UIImageView()
            myImageView.image = myImage
            myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
            myImageView.frame.size.width = imageWidth
            myImageView.frame.size.height = imageHeight
            myImageView.center = self.view.center
            myImageView.frame.origin.y = yPosition
            myScrollView.addSubview(myImageView)
            let spacer:CGFloat = 20
            yPosition+=imageHeight + spacer
            scrollViewContentSize+=imageHeight + spacer
            myScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: imageWidth, height: scrollViewContentSize)
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

> `(for var index=0; index < myImages.count; index++)` error in C-style for statement has been removed in Swift 3

Comment: Just change the C-style for loop to a Swifty one. `for image in myImages { ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **`forEach(_:)`** on `myImages` `array` like so,

```
myImages.forEach {
    if let myImage = UIImage(named: $0) {
        //rest of the code...
    }
}
```

Also, use *optional binding* with `if let` instead of *force unwrapping* the *optional* `UIImage` instance.

Comment: What errors are you getting? I only added the code as per your initial error.